# Photoshop: open 2D texture file at selected point on 3D model

Tags: 3d, photoshop

I've got a 3D file that I am working on, where I need to get colours just right - is there any way to open a specific pixel in the 2D version of the texture by clicking on that point on the 3D model?

I'm on Photoshop CS6 Extended CC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

Open up your 3D model and the 2D texture side by side, so you can see both at once.

Get the brush tool, and hover over the region in the 3D model that you want to find in the 2D version. There will be a crosshair that hovers over the same position in the 2D texture.